# Surrealdb error on create method "invalid type: map, expected a string"

Tags: rust, surrealdb

I am building an API with rust and using surrealdb and I am getting this **"invalid type: map expected a string"** in the `create` method. I am using the official SDK.

This is the complete error:

```bash
Err(Api(FromValue { value: Array(Array([Object(Object({"completed": Bool(false), "content": Strand(Strand("Teste content")), "createdAt": Strand(Strand("2023-12-06T11:51:13.110266200Z")), "id": Thing(Thing { tb: "todo", id: String("47f46af4-27e8-4c22-9711-f49b9a866e82") }), "title": Strand(Strand("Teste")), "updatedAt": Strand(Strand("2023-12-06T11:51:13.110266200Z"))}))])), error: "invalid type: map, expected a string" }))
```

This is the method on the repository:

```rust
// todo_repository.rs

pub async fn create(&self, content: Todo) -> Result<Vec<Todo>, Error> {
    let record = DB.create(&self.table).content(content).await?;
    Ok(record)
}
```

The error is kinda big, so I changed the method to be like in the docs:

```rust
// todo_repository.rs

pub async fn create(&self, content: Todo) -> Result<Vec<Todo>, Error> {
    let record = DB.create("todo").await?;
    Ok(record)
}
```

And this is the new error:

```bash
Err(Api(FromValue { value: Array(Array([Object(Object({"id": Thing(Thing { tb: "todo", id: String("08kipc79181usjbuxlnu") })}))])), error: "invalid type: map, expected a string" }))
```

This is how I am configuring the connection:

```rust
// surreal_context.rs
pub static DB: Lazy<Surreal<Client>> = Lazy::new(Surreal::init);

pub async fn connect_db() -> Result<()> {
    let _ = DB.connect::<Ws>("localhost:8000").await?;
    let _ = DB.signin(Root {
        username: "root",
        password: "root",
    })
    .await;
    let _ = DB.use_ns("todo").use_db("todo").await?;
    Ok(())
}

// main.rs
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _ = connect_db().await;
...
}
```

minimal to reproduce:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use surrealdb::{Surreal, Result, engine::remote::ws::{Client, Ws}, opt::auth::Root};

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct Todo {
    pub id: Option<String>,
    pub title: String,
    pub content: String,
    pub completed: Option<bool>,
    pub createdAt: Option<DateTime<Utc>>,
    pub updatedAt: Option<DateTime<Utc>>,
}


pub static DB: Lazy<Surreal<Client>> = Lazy::new(Surreal::init);

pub async fn connect() -> Result<()> {
    let _ = DB.connect::<Ws>("localhost:8000").await?;
    let _ = DB.signin(Root {
        username: "root",
        password: "root",
    })
    .await;
    let _ = DB.use_ns("todo").use_db("todo").await?;
    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let _ = connect().await;

    let record: Vec<Todo> = DB.create("todo").await?;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

These are the dependencies:

```ini
[dependencies]
axum = "0.7.1"
chrono = { version = "0.4.31", features = ["serde"] }
once_cell = "1.18.0"
serde = { version = "1.0.193", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.108"
surrealdb = "1.0.0"
tokio = { version = "1.34.0", features = ["full"] }
tower-http = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["cors"] }
uuid = { version = "1.6.1", features = ["v4", "serde"] }
```

Comment: Added a minimal reproducible example and the Todo type

Comment: @cafce25 removed "EDIT" thanks for the advices

Comment: Related: [Failed to create record in SurrealDb](/q/76185431/2189130)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the issue, and it turns out the solution is quite straightforward. In surrealdb, the `id` field is essentially "reserved" and is automatically set for all records upon creation. Consequently, when I specified `id: Option<String>`, it conflicted with surrealdb's default serialization, which expects the `id` field to be of type `Thing`.

To overcome this, I opted to rename the `id` field in my `Todo` struct to `_id`, and voila, everything is now functioning as expected now.